# Asterisk PBX - PRI call grouping

Tags: asterisk

I have created a custom IVR using asterisk. The IVR is all about fetching person medical information from DB based on the user input for person id and inform their medical history.

I am having 6 csutomers like(schools and colleges). I am planning to buy a PRI line with 24 channels and distrtibute 4 channel for each customer.4 customers can call at same time to a single DID number. If 5th customer calls it should give busy tone.

Each customer should have a unique number, so i am planning to buy 6 DID numbers from my telecom service provider.

How to achieve this using asterisk pbx or provide me any input to proceed with this

Thanks
Magesh

Answer (score 0):

Group the calls with the GROUP command by dnis

Count the calls that have that dnis

Apply your limits

Something like this...

```
; this is your dialplan
[yourdialplan]
exten => 7314451234,n,Macro(limit-by-did,${EXTEN})
exten => 7314451235,n,Macro(limit-by-did,${EXTEN})
exten => 7314451236,n,Macro(limit-by-did,${EXTEN})
exten => 7314451237,n,Macro(limit-by-did,${EXTEN})
exten => 7314451238,n,Macro(limit-by-did,${EXTEN})


; this does the check
[macro-limit-by-did]
exten => s,1,Verbose(2,"checking limits")

; group by dnis
exten => s,n,Set(GROUP(CLIENT)=${ARG1})

; count number of calls in this dnis that are active
exten => s,n,Set(CLIENT_COUNT=${GROUP_COUNT(${ARG1}@CLIENT)})

; apply the limits jumping to block or pass
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${CLIENT_COUNT} > 4]?block:pass)

; sorry you were 5th caller
exten => s,n(block),Verbose(2,too many callers to ${ARG1})
exten => s,n,Hangup()

; you were less than 5th caller continue on
exten => s,n(pass),Verbose(2,less than 4 callers on ${ARG1})
```